# How can I fix the alignment of the closing tag when using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, indentation

I'm still learning XSLT, but I have no idea how to fix this:

The closing tag `</result>` created by `xsltproc` is still indented as if it were part of the element; for example:

```xml
  <result>
      <channel>netgroup_home_hosts</channel>
      <value>0.006</value>
      <!--thresholds start--><LimitMaxWarning>1</LimitMaxWarning><LimitMaxError>2</LimitMaxError><!--thresholds end-->
      <!--range: min="0"-->
    </result>
```

However I'd like the closing tag to be aligned with the opening tag.
Either I forgot something, or I'm not using XSLT correctly (the extra comments are some debugging left-over).

Here is a (simple) example input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MonitoringOutput id="id-13951" version="0.1">
  <description>input</description>
  <exit_code>0</exit_code>
  <status_string>OK</status_string>
  <info_string>response_time(netgroup:home_hosts) is 0.006 (0)</info_string>
  <perf_string> netgroup_home_hosts=0.006;1;2;0</perf_string>
  <perf_data count="1">
    <sample label="netgroup_home_hosts">
      <label>netgroup_home_hosts</label>
      <value>0.006</value>
      <thresholds>
        <warn end="1"/>
        <crit end="2"/>
      </thresholds>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
</MonitoringOutput>
```

And this is the output created (the comments are for helping me debug XSLT):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--MonitoringOutput v0.1 id=id-13951 (PRTG.xsl v0.0.0)-->
<prtg>
  <!--status_string=OK-->
  <!--success status!-->
  <!--perf_data:-->
  <!--Description: input-->
  <!--Exit Code: 0-->
  <text>OK</text>
  <!--Info String: response_time(netgroup:home_hosts) is 0.006 (0)-->
  <!--Perf String:  netgroup_home_hosts=0.006;1;2;0-->
  <result>
      <channel>netgroup_home_hosts</channel>
      <value>0.006</value>
      <!--thresholds start--><LimitMaxWarning>1</LimitMaxWarning><LimitMaxError\
>2</LimitMaxError><!--thresholds end-->
      <!--range: min="0"-->
    </result>
</prtg>
```

And this is the XSLT (probably overly complicated, but I wanted to get it right first, then optimize):

```xslt
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/MonitoringOutput[@version]">
  <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"
  /> v<xsl:value-of select="@version" /> id=<xsl:value-of select="@id"
  /> (PRTG.xsl v0.0.0)</xsl:comment>
  <xsl:variable name="main.node" select="." />
  <prtg>
    <xsl:comment>status_string=<xsl:value-of
    select="$main.node/status_string" /> </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="perf_data[@count &gt; 0]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$main.node/perf_data/crit_labels[@count &gt; 0]">
            <xsl:comment>critical status!</xsl:comment>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$main.node/perf_data/warn_labels[@count &gt; 0]">
            <xsl:comment>warnings status!</xsl:comment>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:comment>success status!</xsl:comment>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$main.node/perf_data"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <error>1</error>
        <xsl:comment>(<xsl:value-of select="$main.node/exit_code"
        />)</xsl:comment>
        <text><xsl:value-of select="$main.node/info_string" /></text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </prtg>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="perf_data[@count &gt; 0]">
  <!-- no parsing error -->
  <xsl:variable name="main.node" select=".." />
  <xsl:variable name="perf.node" select="." />
  <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />:</xsl:comment>
  <!-- HOW TO? -->
  <xsl:comment>Description: <xsl:value-of select="$main.node/description"
  /></xsl:comment>
  <xsl:comment>Exit Code: <xsl:value-of select="$main.node/exit_code"
  /></xsl:comment>
  <text><xsl:value-of select="$main.node/status_string" /></text>
  <xsl:comment>Info String: <xsl:value-of select="$main.node/info_string"
  /></xsl:comment>
  <xsl:comment>Perf String: <xsl:value-of select="$main.node/perf_string"
  /></xsl:comment>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$perf.node/sample"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="perf_data/sample[@label]">
  <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:variable name="is_crit" select="//crit_labels/name/text() = @label" />
    <xsl:variable name="is_warn" select="//warn_labels/name/text() = @label" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$is_crit">
        <warning>1</warning><xsl:comment>critical!</xsl:comment>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$is_warn">
        <warning>1</warning>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample/label">
  <channel><xsl:value-of select="."/></channel>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample/range[@*]">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:comment>range: <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />="<xsl:value-of
    select="."/>"</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample/unit">
  <CustomUnit><xsl:value-of select="."/></CustomUnit>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample/value">
  <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample/thresholds">
  <xsl:variable name="thresholds.node" select="." />
  <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /> start</xsl:comment>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$thresholds.node/*"/>
  <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /> end</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thresholds/crit[@*]">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:variable name="attr.name" select="name(.)" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$attr.name = 'start'">
        <LimitMinError><xsl:value-of select="." /></LimitMinError>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$attr.name = 'end'">
        <LimitMaxError><xsl:value-of select="." /></LimitMaxError>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="$attr.name" />="<xsl:value-of
        select="." />"</xsl:comment>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thresholds/warn[@*]">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:variable name="attr.name" select="name(.)" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$attr.name = 'start'">
        <LimitMinWarning><xsl:value-of select="." /></LimitMinWarning>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$attr.name = 'end'">
        <LimitMaxWarning><xsl:value-of select="." /></LimitMaxWarning>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="$attr.name" />="<xsl:value-of
        select="." />"</xsl:comment>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Update 2023-08-28

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/76976759/6607497 suggested the problem might be related to processing text nodes, I added the `-v` flag when calling `xsltproc`. I think the interesting part is this (note that I've added a `$` to show where the line consisting of spaces only ends):

```xsltproc
xsltApplyTemplates: node: 'sample'
xsltApplyTemplates: list of 9 nodes
xsltProcessOneNode: no template found for text
xsltDefaultProcessOneNode: copy text
      $
xsltCopyText: copy text
      $
xsltProcessOneNode: applying template 'sample/label' for label
```

The corresponding part of the input should be this:

```xml
  <perf_data count="1">
    <sample label="netgroup_home_hosts">
      <label>netgroup_home_hosts</label>
```

So is it that I have to override some default "copy text"?
Probably my beginner's mistake was assuming "*If I specify nothing, nothing will be done.*"

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: I think the example is reproducible and minimal regarding the input: It's about the simplest non-trivial input. Maybe some XSLT rules don't apply to the minimal input, but as the problem and the solution is unknown yet, I think presenting the complete XSLT makes sense. After all I think that there is no big effort to *reproduce* the result. So *what exactly* is the problem with the example?

Comment: I have no argument with your input. But as I said, I have no intention of wading through your XSLT to find where exactly the specific flaw you complain of  is being created. As for your assumption that *"If I specify nothing, nothing will be done."*, you couldn't be more wrong. If you specify nothing, the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#built-in-rule) will take effect.

Comment: Never mind: The essential hint was that text content (even if just space) is not being ignored, but copied on output. I just had to deal with it somehow.

Comment: That's not an accurate statement. Text is copied to the output only if you apply templates to it (and there is no explicit template that matches it that would prevent it). As for whitespace-only text nodes, if you strip them before any processing take place, then you don't need to deal with them at all, since they won't be there.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Actually your comments are not useful: You complain that you don't want to look into it, but also complain that I (seem to) misunderstand things, or do things wrong. Built-in template rules *did* apply, but you state "Text is copied to the output only if you apply templates to it". Not helpful.

Comment: I stand behind my statement. Whether it's useful to you is up to you. It may be useful to others reading this that wish to expand their understanding of how XSLT works. I am not interested in arguing (and I am not complaining about anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with mismatching indent of `</result>` (and actually the contents of the element was that some whitespace had been being copied to output, even though the content model of the element (e.g: `sample`) had no direct CDATA or PCDTA content.

Realizing that the solution was rather simple:
Either one of the following did work:

```xslt
<xsl:template match="sample/text()">
  <xsl:comment>ignored: "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

```xslt
<xsl:template match="sample/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The first variant was for debugging, putting the ignored text as comment into the output, while the second variant did normalize the space to an empty string like this (`xsltproc` verbose output):

```text
xsltProcessOneNode: applying template 'sample/text()' for text
xsltValueOf: select normalize-space()
xsltValueOf: result ''
```

The final output for the original input now looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--MonitoringOutput v0.1 id=id-13951 (PRTG.xsl v0.0.1)-->
<prtg>
  <!--success status!-->
  <text>OK</text>
  <!--Info String: response_time(netgroup:home_hosts) is 0.006 (0)-->
  <result>
    <channel>netgroup_home_hosts</channel>
    <value>0.006</value>
    <!--thresholds start-->
    <LimitMaxWarning>1</LimitMaxWarning>
    <LimitMaxError>2</LimitMaxError>
    <!--thresholds end-->
  </result>
</prtg>
```

Note: The amount of comments in the output may be different from the example shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76976759/6607497 as I had added many more while debugging the solution, and eventually had removed them all before creating the final output for verification.

Comment: Looking at the example input, it seems that `sample` has no child text nodes other than those used for indentation., i.e. whitespace-only nodes. As you say, such nodes are normalized to an empty string. So it would be much simpler to just  suppress them by`<xsl:template match="sample/text()"/>`. It would be even simpler to strip such nodes right from the beginning (as was already suggested in the other answer).

Comment: The "other answer" strips every node (as I understand it). There are nodes where space may be significant (see the `<perf_string> netgroup_home_hosts=0.006;1;2;0</perf_string>` for example). There is a leading space as part of the string.

Comment: 1. The `xsl:strip-space` instruction strips only text nodes that contain **only** whitespace characters. 2. In the (unlikely) case that you need to strip whitespace-only text nodes only from specific elements, the instruction allows you to specify those elements in its `elements` attribute. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#strip

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, the indentation appears to be correct if you add:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

to the top level of your stylesheet. Apparently at some point you apply templates to the input's text nodes, and this causes whitespace-only nodes to be copied to the output. But I do not intend to hunt for it in your 137 lines of code.